# html5 canvas translate 2D side scrolling camera

Tags: html, canvas, translate

Can anyone help or give ideas on how to use HTML5 canvas translate to make a scrolling camera to follow an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `ctx.translate(x, y)` to move the canvas context while you draw your objects normally.

For more detail and suggestions see my answer here: [2D side scrolling camera view in html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909583/2d-side-scrolling-camera-view-in-html5/7911682#7911682)

The accepted answer for that question is another valid way of doing things but is much worse performance-wise.